# How to implement mutex or object monitor in ZooKeeper?

Tags: concurrency, mutex, apache-zookeeper

I want to implement simple class using `ZooKeeper`

```
    public class ResourceMonitor implements Watcher {
    String name = "/zk_test3";
    ZooKeeper zk;

    public ResourceMonitor() throws IOException {
        zk = new ZooKeeper("localhost:8000", 3000, this);
    }

    public void waitAndGet() {

    }

    public void release() {
        //remove children
    }

    public void process(WatchedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ResourceMonitor:" + event.toString());
    }
}
```

I'm new to ZooKeeper and didn't find such example in ZooKeeper receipts.

Comment: could you expand on your use case, it sounds very much like a distributed lock and a recipe for that is available [here](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/recipes.html#sc_recipes_Locks)

Comment: Yes, seems it is the same concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can find example of distributed lock implementation at [github](https://github.com/mairbek/simple-zoo/blob/master/simple-zoo/src/main/java/com/github/mairbek/zoo/ZooLock.java).
Also you can take a look at [curator](https://github.com/Netflix/curator) zookeeper client which has implementations of [common zk reciepts](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Recipes).